# Programmatically started video opens in blank on iPhone (safari and chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, iphone

There's a video in my page. The code sample:

```
<video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" class="video-home" poster="/poster-video.png">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('video').on('click', function() { $(this)[0].play(); });
</script>
```

As you can see the video should start programmatically when an user clicks on it (there's a play button positioned in the middle of the context) and it actually works on every browser and device but iPhone, when the video is opened in blank. Why is that? How can I avoid this strange behaviour?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `playsinline` attribute.

```
<video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" class="video-home" poster="/poster-video.png" playsinline>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```